# Can't restart or stop Firebird 1.5 on linux

Tags: firebird

I have an ubuntu server running firebird 1.5. It was working fine, but recently it started hanging (firebird does not respond anymore). Even when trying to restart or stop the server, it shows an error:

```
>sudo service firebird1.5-super stop
 * Stopping Firebird 1.5 server manager...
Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".
-Failed to establish a connection.
-Connection reset by peer
can not attach to server
```

What can be happening?

Comment: This could possibly be a ipv4/ipv6 mismatch. If `localhost` resolves to ipv6 `::1` and firebird only binds to ipv4 `127.0.0.1`. I regularly reconfigure `/etc/hosts` to default to 127.0.0.1.but you might also be able to use the ip or `localhost4` somewhere in the firebird config.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the solution, but I believe it is more related to software then database (So if someone knows how to move this to stack overflow please do this).

The problem was that when hibernate (the persistence layer) works with Firebird 1.5, it doesn't create the temporary tables used by hibernate like in other new databases, instead it creates actual tables with the prefix HT_ (HT_SOMETABLE). I tried to deactivate this with a "hack", until now it's working fine, no more hanging and nothing unusual has happened because of this hack.

This is what I did:

I created a custom Firebird dialect to stop hibernate from creating these tables:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect;

public class FirebirdHackedDialect extends FirebirdDialect {

    @Override
    public String getCreateTableString() {
        String sql = "HackParaNaoCriarTabelasNoFirebird: ";
        return sql;
    }

}
```

And set this dialect to the persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.yourpackage.etc.FirebirdHackedDialect"/>
```